# Filter dictionary based on date in python?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that looks like this and the dates are in string format :-

```
{ "2021-04-21" : "Shoes",
  "2021-04-07" : "Clothes"
  "2021-03-19" : "Chocolates"
  "2021-03-12" : "Flowers",
  "2021-03-03" : "Gloves" }
```

And the way i am creating my dict is through a list :-

```
my_order_dictionary = {s[:10]: s[10:] for s in output[1:]}
```

I am trying to get the values for dates older than 30 days ago from the present day, So i did :-

```
d = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
for key,value in my_order_dictionary.items():
    if (key < d):
        print(value)
```

But i get the following error :-

```
    if (key < d):
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'
```

How can i fix the data types and then filter based on date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can format `d` into a string so you can compare it with the dictionary keys.

```
d = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `key` is a str value.

According to your dictionary initialization, each key is a string.
And because your looping through each key of the dictionary, the `key`
variable is also a string. You cannot compare a string with a DateTime object.

You can just use [`datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) to convert the string into a datetime object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to cast the datetime (given as string) to a python datetime object for comparison with `d`. You can do it by datetime's [strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) method.
You have to change your if-statement to get the desired behavior.

```
if (datetime.strptime(key, '%Y-%m-%d') < d):
```

Answer (score 0):

`key` is a string; `d` is a `datetime`.  You have to convert your string dates to `datetime`.  You have a consistent format; I expect that you can handle the conversion with what you already know, yes?

For instance:

```
my_order_dictionary = {datetime.strptime(s[:10], "%y-%m-%d")): s[10:]
                       for s in output[1:]}
```

Comment: "You have to convert your string dates to `datetime`" - Why can't they convert their datetime to a string date instead? Seems to me that would also be more efficient, as it needs only one conversion.

Comment: As it happens, collating sequence for the strings will also work to compare the dates.  However, the built-in date comparison is also quite fast.  I chose converting to datetime, because that will support future uses more "naturally" than strings.